# Limit Flask output

Tags: python, json, flask

following request I have a Flask server with which I transfer data in Json format.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import make_response
import io

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/cases")
def cases():
    f = io.open("file.json", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
    r = make_response(f.read())
    r.mimetype = 'application/json'
    return r
```

This also works so far super, but I don't want all the Json data to be passed, only 100 how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In case the JSON contains *array* of items, you can achieve what you want with something line this:

```py
# ...
import json

@app.route("/cases")
def cases():
    f = io.open("file.json", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    r = make_response(json.dumps(data[:100], indent=4))
    r.mimetype = 'application/json'
    return r
```

Comment: Thank u  very Matchhh